# vscode powershell terminal do not run shellArgs on startup but if I kill it and open it it does

Tags: visual-studio-code

on Windows with the recent version v.1.81.x, my folder projects do not run the shellArgs when I open the projects first time, but if I kill the terminal and start it again (ctrl+j) it works and loads the venv fine.

from .vscode\settings.json

```
    "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": true,
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "powershell -noexit -command \"& {C:\\dist\\venvs\\trk-fullstack-test\\Scripts\\Activate.ps1}\""
    ],
```

Comment: shellArgs is deprecated. Use the new way.

Comment: The linked case above none worked, but this worked:
```    "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\dist\\venvs\\trk-fullstack-test\\Scripts\\python.exe",
```